a bounded measurable function is a uniform limit of increasing bounded simple functions
The problem
Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to [0, +\infty]$. Show that $f$ is a bounded unsigned measurable function if and only if  $f$ is the uniform limit of bounded simple functions.
(From Tao, Introduction to Measure Theory)
Status
I tried a bit, failed looked up some proofs on the net, didn't find one that i could understand, then followed some hint at stackexchange to set up another proof. My main problem is that the proofs I've seen  have derived that some supremum exists because the sequence of functions is converging pointwise. I could not see how to deduce that in-between step. I set up the the main proof first and then tried to do the proof that single deduction in a side proof. I ran into a maze of a construction that probably is too convoluted. I think I've proven it, but am not sure. I hope someone can tell me if and where i went wrong or  show a simpler way. It seems to me that i overlooked something basic, also I'm not sure if I interpreted the infinite intersection well at the end.
Main proof
MTP3.9(4) tells us that if f is measurable f is the supremum $f(x) = \sup_n f_n(x)$ of an increasing
sequence $f_0 \leq f_1 \leq f_2 \dots$ of unsigned simple functions $f_n$, each of
which is bounded with finite measure support. So what is lacking is the uniform convergence.
By P14.4.4, a sequence of functions in $B(\mathbb{R}^d \to [0, +\infty])$
(the space of bounded functions in these spaces) is converging to a function
in $B(\mathbb{R}^d \to [0, +\infty])$ in the metric
$d_{B(\mathbb{R}^d \to [0, +\infty])}$ if and only if
$f_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} f $uniformly in $[0, +\infty]$.
The metric $d_{B(\mathbb{R}^d \to [0, +\infty])}$ is defined as:
$$
d_{B(\mathbb{R}^d \to [0, +\infty])}(f, g) = \sup \{ d_{[0, +\infty]}(f(x), g(x)) : x \in X \}.
$$
Thus, we must prove:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in X} \{ d_{[0, +\infty]}(f_n(x), f(x)) \} = 0.
$$
Because $f_n $is increasing for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d $, we have $f_n(x) \leq f(x) $,
so we can reformulate the problem as:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in X} \{ (f - f_n)(x) \} = 0.
$$
Since $f$ is bounded, we have $A \leq f(x) \leq B$. Let $k$ be an integer and partition
$[A, B]$ into $k$ half-open slices of width $M = \frac{|B - A|}{k}$, with:
$$
A_i = [A + (i - 1)M, A + iM) \quad \text{for } 1 \leq i < k, \quad A_k = [A + (k-1)M, B].
$$
It holds that $\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i = [A, B]$.
Using MTE3.7b$_0$, one concludes:
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^k f^{-1}(A_i) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i\right) = \mathbb{R}^d,
$$
because for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, the property $A \leq f(x) \leq B$ implies that
$f^{-1}([A, B])$ gives all of the domain. Hence $\bigcup_{i=1}^k f^{-1}(A_i)$ is a partition of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
For each $x \in f^{-1}(A_i)$, there exists an $n_x$ such that:
$$
f(x) - f_{n_x}(x) < M,
$$
or equivalently:
$$
n_x = \inf \{ N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \geq N, \, |f(x) - f_n(x)| < M \}.
$$
By pointwise convergence, $n_i = \sup \{ n_x : x \in f^{-1}(A_i) \}$ must be finite
(problematic side proof by contradiction see below). Let $n_k = \max_{1 \leq i \leq k} n_i$ . For any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ ,
$x \in A_i $for some$ i$ , and since $f_n$ is increasing, for $n \geq n_k$ we have:
$$
f(x) - f_n(x) \leq f(x) - f_{n_k}(x) \leq f(x) - f_{n_i}(x) \leq f(x) - f_{n_x}(x) \leq M = \frac{|B - A|}{k}.
$$
As $k \to \infty$ , $n_k$ increases, and thus:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in X} \{ (f - f_n)(x) \} \leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \sup_{x \in X} \{ (f - f_{n_k})(x) \} \leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{|B - A|}{k} = 0.
$$
Problematic side proof.
Assume to the contrary $n_i = \sup \{ n_x : x \in f^{-1}(A_i)\}$ is not finite, that is for every
$n \in \mathbb{N}$ one can find an $x \in f^{-1}(A_i)$  such that $f(x) - f_n(x) > M$,
since $f^{-1}(A_i)$ could be an infinite set even with every $n_x$  itsself being finite  this  could be possible.
Let $P_n$ be the property of a set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ that there is a $x \in C$ such that $f(x) − f_(x)$ > M.
First assume there is a infinite decreasing chain of sets $C_1 \subseteq C_2$ such that
$P_1(C_1)$ is true and $P_2(C_2)$ and so on. We use that assumption of existence to define a
sequnece of points and functions.
We start with an arbitrary  $f_{n_0}$. By our assumption we
can find an $x_0$ in that infinite chain such that $f(x) - f_{n_0}(x_0) > M$. Let $f_{n_0}(x_0) = c_0$.
We know $c_0$ is not in $A_i$.  Let $C_{n_0} = f_{n_0}^{-1}(c_0) \cap f^{-1}(A_i)$.
By pointwise convergence there is an $f_{n_1}$ such that $f(x_0) - f_{n_1}(x_0) < M$.
Now wielding the assumption of the infinite chain we can find a new value $x_1 \in C_{n_0}$ such that $f(x_1) - f_{n_1}(x_1) > M$.
Name $f_{n_1}(x_1) = c_1$, and $C_{n1} = f_{n_1}^{-1}(c_1) \cap C_{n_0}$. This process now we carry on infinite times, which is
possible by the infinite decreasing chain.
Consider:
$$
C = \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty C_{ni}.
$$
The infinite chain tells us that C is non-empty. But this says there are x not converging, hence such a
infinite chain cannot exist.
So since such an infinite chain does not exist, in the algorithm above one has at
some time switch preimages choosing the $x_i$ from $f_{n_0}^{-1}(c_0) ∩ f⁻¹(A_i)$ to
$f_{n_0}^{-1}(c_j) ∩ f⁻¹(A_i)$ for some other value $c_j$ of $f_{n_0}$. But because
$f_{n_0}$ is simple there are also finite such value, so the process cannot go on
infinitely. Hence $n_i = \sup \{ n_x : x \in f^{-1}(A_i)\}$ is finite.

I think you've misunderstood.  The statement "f is the uniform limit of bounded simple functions" means that there exists a sequence $f_n$ of bounded simple functions that converges uniformly to $f$.
3.9(4) asserts that there exists a increasing sequence of bounded simple functions $f_n$, each with finite support, that converge pointwise to $f$.  But this is not (necessarily) the sequence you are looking for.  It's not true that every such sequence must converge uniformly to $f$.
Consider for instance $f=1_{(0,1)}$ and $f_n = 1_{(1/n,1)}$.  This sequence satisfies the conclusion of 3.9(4) (increasing, pointwise convergent, etc), but it does not converge to $f$ uniformly.
The flaw in your side proof is at the sentence "The infinite chain tells us that C is non-empty."  There's no such fact.  It's entirely possible for a descending chain of nonempty sets to have empty intersection.  In the example above, the set $C_{n_i}$ is going to be something like $(0, 1/i]$ and the intersection of those is most certainly empty.
You might be thinking of the fact that a descending chain of nonempty compact sets has nonempty intersection.  But since here we are only assuming that $f, f_n$ are measurable, there is no reason for the sets we are working with to be compact.
(If the increasing sequence of functions $f_n$, as well as $f$ itself, were continuous and defined on a compact domain, then you could in fact conclude that they converge uniformly.  This is Dini's theorem.  Indeed one can prove it by an argument very similar to what's in your side proof, since in that case (choosing $A_i$ a bit differently) one gets a descending chain of compact sets.)
So to prove your desired statement, you have to actually construct such a sequence $f_n$.  You can't just invoke the statement of 3.9(4).  It's possible that 3.9(4) is proved by constructing a sequence that happens to also converge uniformly, in which case you may be able to adapt its construction.

Thanks, this sheds light for me.
